# Qt QLineEdit Input Validation

Tags: qt, validation, qregexp, input-mask, qregularexpression

How would one set an input validator on a `QLineEdit` such that it restricts it to a valid IP address? i.e. x.x.x.x where x must be between 0 and 255.and x can not be empty

Comment: Have you read the docs of `QValidator`? Start from there. You have basically two options, create your own subclass "IpValidator", or use the regular expression validators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Input Mask and QValidator to a QLineEdit at a time in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166283/how-to-set-input-mask-and-qvalidator-to-a-qlineedit-at-a-time-in-qt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166283/how-to-set-input-mask-and-qvalidator-to-a-qlineedit-at-a-time-in-qt)

In short: You have to set `QRegExpValidator` with the appropriate Regular Expression for IP4 adresses.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qregexp.html) and [QValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html), to validate an IPv4 use this expresion:

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-‌​9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)‌​\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-‌​9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)‌​\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-‌​9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)‌​\b
```

Example:

```
QRegExp ipREX("\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-‌​9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)‌​\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-‌​9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)‌​\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-‌​9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)‌​\b");
ipREX.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
ipREX.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::RegExp);
```

Now, use it as validator of your text lineedit:

```
QRegExpValidator regValidator( rx, 0 );
ui->lineEdit->setValidator( &regValidator );
```

Now, just read your input and the validator will validate it =). If you want to do it manually, try something like this:

```
ui->lineEdit->setText( "000.000.000.000" );
const QString input = ui->lineEdit->text();
// To check if the text is valid:
qDebug() << "IP validation: " << myREX.exactMatch(input);
```

There is another way to made it using Qt classes, [QHostAddress](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qhostaddress.html) and [QAbstractSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html):

```
QHostAddress address(input);
if (QAbstractSocket::IPv4Protocol == address.protocol())
{
   qDebug("Valid IPv4 address.");
}
else if (QAbstractSocket::IPv6Protocol == address.protocol())
{
   qDebug("Valid IPv6 address.");
}
else
{
   qDebug("Unknown or invalid address.");
}
```

Comment: It is taking the value greater than 255 also. and we can enter 133.133. instead of 4 parts. it is able to take less than 4 parts of ip address. Please suggest how we can validate that ip address must contain 4 parts with range 0-255

Comment: See my last changes. Here's the best one I've found so far:

\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b