# How did I retrieve changes in the content of all text edit boxs in a widget

Tags: qt

Now, I have a widget that used for conguring some parameters, There were some `QlineEdit` with default value and a `save` button on this widget. People may change the content of `QlineEdit`. And click the `save` button, so that the modified parameters can take effect. Here is my question:

How do retrieve changes  in the content of all text line edit in this `QWidget`?

Once I know which edit content has changed, I can judge whether the modified values is legal, and then let the change take effect.

Can anyone give me some ideas?

- OS: Windows10
- QT: qt 5.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this situation, It's better to do one more step before manually validating the user's input. The step is to limit the user to enter invalid settings. If your setting value is a number, use [QSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html) or [QDoubleSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html) for floating-point values. If you want to let the user select from multiple predefined values, like gender(Male, Female), use [QComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) or [QRadioButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qradiobutton.html) and so forth. Here is the list of [Qt's widgets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/widget-classes.html). So bear in mind, using QLineEdit for all of the inputs is not a good idea.

If your input is something more complex, you can use validators. For getting the idea see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202697/qt-qlineedit-input-validation).

At last, you connect the save button's [clicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal to the slot defined in your widget class using Qt's [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) mechanism and get values from all of your inputs and check them, and if everything is OK, apply them to your system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have other problem that is how do I know that the content of the `textBox` or `QcomboBox` has changed without comparing the content of the control with the previous value. You know if the setting paramters are not changed, I don't need to apply these setting again. However, I have a lot of configuration items, and it seems a bit too complicated to judge one by one .

Comment: @gavin_free QComboBox has few signals which let you know it has changed. See the documentation. It's not needed to compare. Mail me if you want...